# Make a "java -jar file.jar" run at startup

Tags: ubuntu, startup, kubuntu

Hello I am running a kubuntu 13.10 distro, but I guess my question is pretty general...how to make a .jar execute in background at system start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your command in file `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

java -jar file.jar &

exit 0
```

Comment: Instead of exiting 0, would it be better to exit with $?

Comment: will it run as a background task this way? Or do I need to explicitely set a "&" after the command?

Comment: Adding `&` to your command to make it running in background.